# BlackBerry JavaScript API for native (or native-like) controls

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, user-interface, mobile

Are there any javascript libraries or APIs that would allow a website too look more 'native' on a BlackBerry phone? I'm talking about things like being able to use the trackball to focus/highlight on elements, and add options to the contextual menu (the Blackberry button).

I look at WebWorks a bit but it seems that it is a tool for packaging a website into an app, rather than what I am looking for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

WebWorks combined with a JavaScript UI library may get you what you are looking for. We are using WebWorks (gives you access to device features such as the menu) and JQuery Mobile (for the "native" UI look...looks more like iPhone).

JQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/) look and feel can be customized with their ThemeRoller to get it to look more like what you want.

Beware, there are features of JQuery Mobile that are unsupported in BB 5.0. As long as you are targeting BB 6.0 and above, you'll be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use BBUI, it's Blackberry's official Javascript library : https://github.com/tneil/bbUI.js